# Browser extension, - Accessing the images before rendering

Tags: c#, image, browser, rendering

I'm a photographer with a good IT background.

I'm looking to intercept the rendering of images in websites, possibly through a browser extension. My plan is to identify the use of my photos automatically when browsing the web.

So what I need to do - you tell me the best way how please:) - is to intercept the rendering of the image, read the image and possibly modify it.

Are extensions/addOns a good approach? Is there another way? Possibly using c#...

Cheers
Marc

Comment: You probably could do it as a browser extension, however, it will obviously work only for people who install it. Also, it's very browser-specific, so without saying which browser you're targeting you're unlikely to get an answer (not that I will answer anyway, I've never written a browser extension myself :) ) Just out of curiosity, if I may - what do you need this for?

Comment: Yes, extensions, I'm aiming at Firefox and out of interest maybe IE8+. Cross-browser would be awesome, though. I will be the only one who installs it so that's fine. I cannot find a starting point for that particular job, using extensions. Not using Yahoogle anyway.

Comment: You might also think in a different direction. A cross-browser solution is to create a web proxy. You can probably find an open-source one, then modify so that it handles images before passing them on to the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Digital Rights Management (DRM).  You as well as Hollyweird would love to stop everyone from free viewing.  But once its on the web, only laywers can stop people viewing.

Here's a good place to start your research.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management

Comment: Thank you. But that's not what I want. I don't want to protect them, I want to detect them.

Answer (score 0):

If your photo's are hosted on ImageShack.us for example you wont be able to intercept the rendering. IMHO the closest you could get is using a watermark.

However if you host the images on your server and render them out using a ashx in C# then you can read the image and modify it before its rendered.

Take this code as an example:
http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/

```
<%@ webhandler language="C#" class="NWEmpPhotoHandler" %>
using System; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
public class NWEmpPhotoHandler : IHttpHandler 
{ 
    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } } 

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx) 
    { 
        string id = ctx.Request.QueryString["id"]; 

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(<<INSERT CONNECTION STRING HERE>>); 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Photo FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpID", con); 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", id); 

        con.Open(); 
        byte[] pict = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
        con.Close(); 

        ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"; 
        ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(pict, 78, pict.Length - 78); 
    } 
}
```

So you'd hit the ashx with a url like:  www.Marc.com/Images.ashx?id=123

Alternatively with your browser extension approach, you could have a local repository of images or perhaps specific image names (using GUIDs) and when loading a page detect if any of the images are yours and then do your black magic.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I want to scan for images that come are displayed on any website. Not mine. So I cannot access a database, I have to stick to what the browser gives me - hence I started looking at browser extensions/plugins/addOns. Is there a way? There must be!